# How do I re-show a hidden website on Chrome's new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

I've accidentally clicked the "X" to hide a specific website from showing in my recent/most popular pages. How can I get it back?

Comment: @DaveRook It is. I searched and couldn't find that thread, worded a little weird.

Comment: This is most certainly NOT a duplicate as marked!  What's worse: I have a good answer for this question, but can't add it because of this erroneous duplicate prevents any more answers.  Sorry folks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may not be your ideal solution - but the way I was once told to do it was to delete another tab thumbnail and then when the "undo" button appears - click "Restore All".

It will mean that you need to hide a potential load more tab thumbs that you don't want, but it will revive the one that you do!

Since this behaviour can be a pain to work with, it might also be worth looking at extensions such as "speed dial 2" to manage your new tab page lists.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a fantastic solution for anyone who doesn't mind resetting the whole New Tab page without having to reset _everything_ in Chrome. It does have the downside of unhiding all sites, but you can of course re-hide the ones you want to hide again.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than I thought. Hide another page on that screen and then click "Restore All" after the alert at the bottom of the page shows up.